# Nested fonts not working

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to get some words in bold and typewriter styles together but only typewriter is been applied. I saw in other question one not should use \bf while nesting, so I tried:

```
\texttt{\textbf{Mywords}}
\textbf{\texttt{Other words}}
```

but both of them appear only with typewriter style. I'm in a document class `scrreprt.`

Comment: The standard fonts don't have boldface typewriter type. You get it if you add `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: You need a typewriter font where a bold variant exists, e.g. LuxiMono